# Curvature calculation of $S^{2n+1}=U(n+1)/U(n)$ as a homogeneous space

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, submanifold, homogeneous-spaces

I eventually want to check how the Hopf fibration
$$
S^{2n+1}\to {\mathbb C}P^n
$$
satisfies the Riemannian submersion formula, but I am frustrated that I could not even see how things work for $S^{2n+1}$ alone.

I can take either of the models
$$
S^{2n+1} = U(n+1)/U(n) = SU(n+1)/SU(n+1),
$$
but maybe the first is easier.

Then $G=U(n+1), H=U(n), {\mathfrak g}={\mathfrak u}(n+1), {\mathfrak h}={\mathfrak u}(n)$, diagonally embedded in ${\mathfrak u}(n+1)$ with the last entry 0. Let the invariant metric be
$$
\langle A, B\rangle = -\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Re Tr }AB = \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Re Tr} AB^*.$$
Let
$${\mathfrak m} = {\mathfrak h}^\perp, 
$$
whose dimension is $2n+1$. I am supposed to check that for any orthonormal $X, Y\in {\mathfrak m}$, the sectional curvature
$$
K(X, Y) = 1.
$$

Note that for the ${\mathbb C}P^n=SU(n+1)/U(n)$ case, the $K$ ranges from 1 to 4, and I can see that in this calculation, depending on if $X$ and $Y$ are in a complex subspace.

Then I don't see how it works out in the $S^{2n+1}$ case, as we should always have $K$ as a constant 1. I undestand that in this case, $[{\mathfrak m}, {\mathfrak m}]\not\subset {\mathfrak h}$, so I need to use the more general formula (Cheeger & Ebin, Cor. 3.33)
$$
K(X, Y) = \frac{1}{4} \|[X, Y]_{\mathfrak m}\|^2 + \|[X, Y]_{\mathfrak h}\|^2,
$$
but it still would not work for me.

If $X, Y$ are in a complex subspace, say
\begin{align}
X&=E_{1, n+1}-E_{n+1, 1}, \\
Y&=i(E_{1, n+1}+E_{n+1, 1}), \text{ then}\\
[X, Y] &= 2iE_{1, 1} - 2iE_{n+1,n+1}.
\end{align}
I would get $2\frac{1}{2}$ as my answer.

I know I may be too obsessed, and this could be a normalization issue, but your help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question has been reposted at MathOverflow, and has an answer there. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460449/curvature-calculation-of-s2n1-un1-un-as-a-homogeneous-space/460590#460590